# Suggestion wanted for the following scenario ---

Tags: games, kiosk

I have been asked to suggest a solution for the following.

- 3 PCs on a separate network. (not a problem)
- 2 of them only running some sort of text based chat program.
- The other PC will be used to monitor the chat and try to disrupt and confuse the other two PCs' conversation.

The premise of this is that each of the first 2 PCs are trying to solve something for the other user so have to cooperate and the third is trying to make it harder or perhaps help.

Any thoughts or suggestions please?

Comment: What's the question and how does it relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: Well because I want to use Ubuntu of course? I just need some suggestions for the text based chat part.

Answer (score 0):

> 2 of them only running some sort of **text based chat program**

- install a server version for those 2 machines.
- create a normal user on each machine.
- change the `.profile` of those users to start your chat program.

Besides this you will need to tell them how to shutdown/reboot. But that can be done from a bash script  to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: ok thanks its the 3rd pc being able to add messages that causes the problem mainly. It is not wanted for the first 2 to be able to tell who the extra messages are from as it would spoil the scenario they are playing.